# apache 2.4 AliasMatch possible to pass get parameters?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, httpd.conf

Is it possible to pass appended `get` parameters using AlisaMatch in Apache 2.4 on linux?

I would like to do a redirect for a folder that is outside of `DocumentRoot`, so `RewriteRule` will not work in `.htaccess`. Trying `AliasMatch` it seems like the redirect is looking for a file named `/home/other/index.php?a=$1&b=$2` rather than `/home/other/index.php` plus appended get parameters `?a=$1&b=$2`

```
AliasMatch "^/myfolder/(.*)/(.*)$" "/home/other/index.php?a=$1&b=$2"
```

**UPDATE**
Using `RewriteRule` in `htaccess` with full dir path does work as expected.

Comment: question, why don't you use mod_rewrite in virtualhost context the same you had to do with AliasMatch which is also not valid in .htaccess? Remember .htaccess is not a depot for rewrites, just means for non-admins to configure directives in specific directories!

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use `AliasMatch` here just use `Alias` with these directives in Apache config or vhost config:

```
Alias "/myfolder" "/home/other"

<Directory /home/other>
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
   AllowOverride All
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
   Require all granted

   RewriteEngine On

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?a=$1&b=$2 [L,QSA]

</Directory>
```

PS: If you want, you may also use this rule inside `/home/other/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?a=$1&b=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: this does not seem to work in the .`conf` as expected. I still can only get a redirect in`.htaccess` using full path, not a relative path.

Comment: Before posting I have verified these rules working fine from my vhost.conf and .htaccess files.